# How do I get data from Mongoose in Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get some data from Mongoose using Express. I have created a username and password form to log in to my site. It is supposed to check the credentials and let them in if the credentials are the same as the ones stored on the database, but it is letting anything in (even if I put the wrong password). My source files seem fine, and the console is not throwing any errors. The Gists to the files are below:

[login.ejs](https://gist.github.com/safsom/314f61eca99a8827f00134828e1e062b)

[register.ejs](https://gist.github.com/263d7152668f440b329bb3e94a907724)

And the app.js file (can't gist it due to my reputation):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var app = express();

var options = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    },
    replset: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 300000,
            connectTimeoutMS : 30000
        }
    }
};

var db =    mongoose.connect('db_uri', options);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname+'/public/templates');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/registerPage', function (req, res) {
    res.render('register') ;
});

app.get('/loginPage', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var user = new User({
    email: email,
    password: password
});
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.dir(user);
        res.send('Account created successfully (email): ' + email);
     });
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    User.findOne( {email: email, password: password}, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('portal');
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You left out the most important part: your application code. Please add the relevant part of it to your question (inline, not as a link).

Comment: This is pretty general but there are a lot of guides with examples that you might find helpful. [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications) is a pretty good one.

Comment: @robertklep I have added the source code, please check it out if you must!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the login handler, you're not actually checking if the query matches a user.

Perhaps you assume that `err` will be set in that case, but it won't be, because the query itself was performed successfully (it just didn't return any records).

You need to add an additional check to see if the query returned a valid user:

```
User.findOne( {email: email, password: password}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (! user) return res.send(401);
    res.render('portal');
});
```

This will return a 401 ("Unauthorized") when the query didn't match a user.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just what I needed!